# How do I run a downloaded file in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, files

My server was running plesk 11, but I removed some of the plesk packages by mistake when i tried to install `postfix` as i wanted to fix problems that i was having with emails.

So now I am attempting to reinstall plesk using the packages from: http://www.parallels.com/download/plesk/10/

I downloaded **parallels_installer_v3.12.0_build120601.16_os_Ubuntu_10.04_i386** for my Ubuntu 10.4 32-bit.

I have added to folder path /plesk/parallels_installer_v3.12.0_build120601.16_os_Ubuntu_10.04_i386 but when i run: `/plesk/parallels_installer_v3.12.0_build120601.16_os_Ubuntu_10.04_i386' in the terminal nothing happens

**Update**

I have since found that the above command was the correct command to run. My problem as seen below was that the correct permissions were not given.

Running the correct command and having permissions will not display any errors.

Comment: Did you read through their [Installation Guide](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP10/10.4/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-installation-upgrade-guide/index.htm)? Also, [SF] is for Professional System Administrators (et al) only. Using Plesk is a huge indication that you are not. [SU] and [Unix.SE] are great sites for enthusiasts and non-Administrator types.

Comment: I think you're being a little unfair here chris S. Blocking me from serverfault... I have searched through hundreds of questions relating to plesk... 1,877

Comment: 1. I'm not "blocking you", I closed a question. 2. You're free to edit this into a professional quality question and I'd be glad to reopen it. 3. There are 559 questions relating to Plesk, not sure where your 1877 number came from.  4. See [Are cpanel questions really 'professional sysadmin' related?](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/3425), the [FAQ], and [How can I ask better questions on Server Fault?](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/3608). 5. Thank you!

Comment: appreciate the reply Chris. Obviously it wasn't you then, but if I got to ask more questions on serverfault I get `Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more.` I have since wiped my server and just gone with a plain ubuntu stack. Been waiting it for years and finally got it. Still, this bores you no doubt :)

Comment: O ye, from doing a search for plesk... I didn't search under the tag.

Comment: Updated the question title and question as to give more information and also help anybody else trying to run a file via command line. Might be we could get the close removed?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Plesk; it's [a very basic Linux question](http://linuxcommand.org/lts0070.php). As such it is _still_ off topic; see the [FAQ]. For your question ban, [that's a separate issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/189912).

Comment: @MichaelHampton the updated question removes any issue to do with plesk... plesk was just the issue I originally what I thought was causing the problem. Now is it not helpful for users to know this? Or is it to basic to help people that are Professional?

Comment: This being something you generally learn within the first week of using Linux, if not the very first day, yes it's too basic.

Comment: indeed, this is my first week using ubuntu :) at least without plesk. Anyway fair one. I don't see much point in keeping this question on the site do you?

Comment: No, but you _really_ should read the link I gave you about your question ban and act on that before you go deleting this question.

Comment: Ye, just in the process of trying to fix things ;) I've updated all my questions and am trying to answer questions where possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the space in server

```
$sudo chmod +x parallels_installer_v3.12.0_build120601.16_os_Ubuntu_10.04_i386 
$sudo ./parallels_installer_v3.12.0_build120601.16_os_Ubuntu_10.04_i386 --web-interface

http://localhost:8447
```

Comment: was permissions issue.